# Are there multiple animatronics in Five Nights at Freddy's 3?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

I've been watching videos about FNAF3 and my friend thinks the only animatronic is Springtrap. In the videos I saw the player got killed by Phantom Foxy but he still doubts me. He backed himself and said that the other animatronics are just hallucinations made by Springtrap. I'm kind of confused if they are hallucinations or if there is multiple animatronics. Can somebody who actually knows tell me if there are multiple animatronics in FNAF3?

Comment: AFAIK There is only springtrap that is "real". Dont have enough info to confirm tho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is only one animatronic: **Springtrap**. Every other "animatronic", referred to as Phantoms in the Extras menu (*Phantom Bonnie, Phantom Freddy, Phantom Marionette, Phantom BB, Phantom Foxy, Phantom Chica*) are hallucinations caused by poor ventilation.  This is why on Day 1 the phone guy specifically tells the player to make sure the ventilation works, otherwise you'll start to see "stuff".

Comment: Is it the lack of ventilation that kills you not the actual hallucinations?

Comment: When the Phantom versions "kill" the player it is really just a jump scare.  The screen will darken, but then come back with the ventilation alarm going off.  Basically, the only way to get a Game Over is to be killed by Springtrap.

Comment: Basically the hallucinations keep you distracted long enough to allow Springtrap to get to you. Think of it like Five Nights at Freddys 1, where if you didn't watch Chica through the cameras carefully and you allowed her to get outside your office she would start clicking and preventing you from shutting down or securing the security doors.

Answer (score 3):

From Steam's main page on the game (http://store.steampowered.com/app/354140/):

> **About This Game**
>
> Thirty years after Freddy Fazbear's Pizza closed it's doors, the events that took place there have become nothing more than a rumor and a childhood memory, but the owners of "Fazbear's Fright: The Horror Attraction" are determined to revive the legend and make the experience as authentic as possible for patrons, going to great lengths to find anything that might have survived decades of neglect and ruin.
>
> At first there were only empty shells, a hand, a hook, an old paper-plate doll, but then a remarkable discovery was made...
>
> The attraction now has one animatronic.

Short answer - read the bottom line.  There is one animatronic.

Comment: But how does the other animatronics kill you if there is only one real animatronic?

Comment: Is this not explained in the game as hallucinations?

Comment: @Mr.Advice - see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/208678/101016 regarding the ingame explanation.

Answer (score 1):

there is springtrap
PHANTOMS: chica, freddy, puppet, balloon boy, foxy

PS Bonnie isn't in it, springtrap is an older version of him

PPS There is also a balloon girl, which fixes your stuff when the phantom animatronics break them.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one animatronic and that's Springtrap. The other animatronics are you seeing things in the game because of the ventilation breaking down.

Plus, I think Scott said in something for Five nights at Freddy's 3 "only one" meaning only one animatronic in the game.

Answer (score -3):

According to my theory: There *could* be only one animatronic, which I believe is Phone Guy. This is because on night 4 in Five Nights At Freddy's 2, Phone Guy ends his call by getting killed by Golden Freddy. So Golden Freddy must have stuffed him into a suit, you can see his bloodstains and his brain on the right top corner of the animatronic. Also there's only one animatronic because the last restaurant they scraped the animatronics (even the secret ones) and put their parts in a box like the pictures Scott Cawthon put. There is a trailer if you want to see it. Phone Guy was not scraped and he is worn out because this restaurant takes place 30 years after the previous restaurant from Five Nights At Freddy's 2.

Comment: And [again](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/206973/how-do-i-edit-a-tombstone#comment279871_206973), Capitalizing The First Letter Of Every Word Is Unneccessary And Annoying.

Comment: I was bored, so I attempted to make this something resembling readable. However there were a couple rambly-bits that I couldn't make heads or tails of. The images were largely superfluous and did not seem to add anything to the answer.

Comment: Also phone guy dies in FNAF 1. Also, loads of spoilers.